$A^2=A=A^*$ iff $Im A$ and $Im (I-A)$ is orthogonal
Here $A^*$ means the conjugate transpose of $A$ and $Im A$ means the image space of $A$.
I can get the necessity.Because $A^2=A$ means $A$ is a projection matrix ,then for $w_1\in Im A$ and $w_2\in Im (I-A)$,$Aw_1=w_1$ and $Aw_2=0$,so $(w_1,w_2)=(Aw_1,w_2)=(w_1,A^*w_2)=0$.
How can I get the sufficiency?

Start with $(Ax,y-Ay)=0$ and see how far you can get.

Oh,I get it .Thanks a lot

For any $x,y$,$0=(Ax,(I-A)y)=(x,A^*(I-A)y)$,thus $A^*=A^*A$.Similarly $0=(Ax,(I-A)y)=((I-A^*)Ax,y)$,then $A=A^*A$.The sufficiency follows.
